# How to animate a UILabel after another

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I currently animate two `UILabel` as such:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0];
[_temperatureLabel setAlpha:1];
[_tempDescriptionLabel setAlpha:1];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

However, I want to show the first label `_temperatureLabel` then once that is done animating (or maybe halfway through) start animating the second label `_tempDescriptionLabel`.

Comment: @Ilario answer is definitely the easiest way to do this. If you want to have one start half-way through the first animation, that is quite a bit more involved. I would use keyframes in that instance: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coreanimation_guide/CreatingBasicAnimations/CreatingBasicAnimations.html

Comment: @MySpecialPurpose yes i know, my answer is easy, and does not allow to start an animation in the middle of the other, but it works obv

Comment: @Ilario Was not trying to offend you, sorry if I did! I agree with you and that's exactly how I would do this too. I was simply pointing out that the OP said he might want to have the animation start halfway through. I was simply pointing out a method he could use to do that.

Comment: @MySpecialPurpose oh no no you got it wrong, I'm not offended, I was saying that you are right and that I have shown only the easiest way to do an animation in sequence ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as I said I'll answer:

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:2 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{

         //set alpha 1 for first UILabel
         _temperatureLabel.alpha = 1;

        } completion:^(BOOL finished){

        [UIView animateWithDuration:2 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{

                //when finished enter here
            //set alpha 1 for second UILabel
            _tempDescriptionLabel.alpha = 1;

            } completion:^(BOOL finished){


            }];

        }];
```

remember to add `QuartzCore` framework, and add `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`

Comment: Works like a charm! I didn't need to import QuartzCore though (it was added though) I kinda faked the halfway duration by having the label alpha reach to .5 and letting it reach 1 in the next block

Answer (score 0):

For doing halfWay or any other mid way time,

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0];
[_temperatureLabel setAlpha:1];
[UIView commitAnimations];
[self performSelector:@selector(halfWayStart:) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];

-(void)halfWayStart:(id)object{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0];
    [_tempDescriptionLabel setAlpha:1];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

so, changing the `afterDelay` time value in `performSelector` call will help you to start other animation any time.